# Need to stay clicked on row to select it

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have an issue with my UITableView.

The method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is not called until I stay clicked on the row for 2 seconds minimum. If I just click one time on the cell like a normal person would do to select it, nothing happens : didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't called.

[image: My prototype cell attributes]

[image: My Table View attributes]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithSelection" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *player = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = [TCUtilities defaultAttributedStringWithString:[player objectForKey:@"personalName"] AndSize:DEFAULT_SIZE AndColor:DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

Comment: I see you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. How is designed the cell with reuse identifier `CellWithSelection` in your interface builder? Moreover, have you a gesture recognizer on your view?

Comment: Thanks zbMax! I forgot about this gesture recognizer in my viewDidLoad. It's fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed thanks to zbMax.
I had a gesture recognizer implemented in my viewDidLoad method.